# Is it possible to read HTML in CSS?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Google Chrome extension to change the appearance of the (Webkit) scrollbars. I want them to "blend in" with the rest of the page. What I was thinking of doing is reading the page's background colour and assigning it to the background-color of ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece. Is this possible?

Also, is it possible to tell if the scrollbar I'm changing is one of the main ones (as opposed to an in-page one).

P.S: I'm really a beginner when it comes to web development.

Comment: CSS can't, but it shouldn't be hard for a Chrome Extension to do so using some JavaScript.

Comment: @ceejayoz, how do I send the JavaScript result back to CSS? This may be my answer.

Comment: You'd use JavaScript to inject some CSS into the DOM. Here's an extension that does it that you should be able to download and examine: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/hiadkoalmmkgennhcldmdlndfgagkcim

Comment: Sorry, I can't quite figure this out. Can someone explain? I'm not good at DOM.

Answer (score 1):

With a content script you can read the CSS data, and then inject the proper styles on to the page.

As an example, the following will style just the "body" scrollbars:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {background-color:#000}
```

Comment: Are the body scrollbars the "main" ones?

Comment: Yes, the `body` is the main container, but in more complex sites the scrollbars could come from other elements. But should work in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it in pure CSS, You'd need at least Javascript to accomplish this, but it's probably impossible in Chrome, and for good reason.

The last time I remember this being possible is in IE6. It's a risky idea in general to change user interface elements that are common to all applications on a platform, because the user has to relearn how to use your application.

Think of the best-designed sites on the internet. You probably don't spend much time wishing their scrollbars blended in better. It's just unnecessary, and the downside (confusing the user) far outweighs the upside (possibly making the scrollbars slightly prettier).

Comment: Chrome supports scrollbar styling: http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/overflow-scrollbar-combinations.html

Comment: I understand your point, but, as it is an extension I am making, it is up to the user to decide if they want it. There is a "no scrollbar" extension which I used for a bit, until I wanted to know how long the page was. This is my replacement for it, a compromise.